# Custom ordering using Java Comparator - Retain the position for objects with certain value

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream, comparator

I am trying to implement a custom comparator that sorts a list of objects in descending order, but while doing so, it ignores when the object has a specific value (-1 in my case). Thus, the objects with that value retain their original position, but all the objects around them will be sorted in descending order. For example, if the list is :

```
Candidate candidate1 = new Candidate("id1",  0.4);
Candidate candidate2 = new Candidate("id2", -1.0);
Candidate candidate3 = new Candidate("id3", 0.8);
List<Candidate> inputCandidates = ImmutableList.of(candidate1, candidate2, candidate3)
```

The resulting order should be

```
[
    Candidate(super=Candidate(id=id3), value=0.8), 
    Candidate(super=Candidate(id=id2), value=-1.0), 
    Candidate(super=Candidate(id=id1), value=0.4)
]
```

Currently, I am trying something like this:

```
public final Comparator<Candidate> customComparator() {
    return (Candidate one, Candidate two) -> {
        double scoreOne =  one.getValue() != null ? one.getValue() : 0d;
        double scoreTwo =  two.getValue() != null ? two.getValue() : 0d;
        if (scoreOne == scoreTwo) return 0;
        if (scoreOne == -1.0d) return 1;
        if (scoreTwo == -1.0d) return -1;
        return Double.compare(scoreTwo, scoreOne);
    };
}
```

However, this instead gives me:

```
[
    Candidate(super=Candidate(id=id3), value=0.8), 
    Candidate(super=Candidate(id=id1), value=0.4), 
    Candidate(super=Candidate(id=id2), value=-1.0)
]
```

Could someone please help me figure out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution using a single `Comparator` (or at least I failed to find it so). Here is a working solution requiring two steps:

1. Sort all the values in the descending (`reversed()`) order **without** the specific value and collect it as a mutable list:

   ```java
   List<Candidate> sorted = inputCandidates.stream()
        .filter(candidate -> candidate.getValue() != -1.0)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Candidate::getValue).reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
   ```
2. Iterate through the **former** collection and add the candidates **with** the specific value (`-1.0`) to its original index position in the newly sorted list:

   ```java
   for (int i=0; i<inputCandidates.size(); i++) {
        Candidate candidate = inputCandidates.get(i);
        if (candidate.getValue() == -1.0) {
            sorted.add(i, candidate);
        }
    }
   ```

---

Example input:

> ```
> Candidate candidate1 = new Candidate("id1",  0.4);
> Candidate candidate2 = new Candidate("id2", -1.0); // fixed position
> Candidate candidate3 = new Candidate("id3", -1.0); // fixed position
> Candidate candidate4 = new Candidate("id4",  0.8); 
> Candidate candidate5 = new Candidate("id5", -1.0); // fixed position
> Candidate candidate6 = new Candidate("id6",  0.5);
> ```

Example output:

```java
sorted.forEach(c -> System.out.println(c.getId() + " : " + c.getValue()));
```

> ```
> id4 : 0.8
> id2 : -1.0  // fixed position    
> id3 : -1.0  // fixed position
> id6 : 0.5 
> id5 : -1.0  // fixed position
> id1 : 0.4
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Great question.

I don't believe there is any functionality that allows you to do this.
For example, with *[streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html)*.

Here is a concept you can use.

First, identify the indices that you'd like to preserve, and create a *[Map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html)* to hold the data.

Using the *map*, remove each of the identified values, from the original list.

Sort the list collection, and then add, back in, the identified values.

```java
/* original content */
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of('d', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c'));

/* identified, preserved values */
char[] values = { 'e', 'b' };

/* map each identified value */
Map<Integer, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
for (char value : values) map.put(list.indexOf(value), value);

/* remove identified indices, from list */
for (int index = list.size() - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
    if (map.containsKey(index)) list.remove(index);
}

/* sort the list */
Collections.sort(list);

/* add in the identified values */
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Character> entry : map.entrySet())
    list.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
```

Here is the original list, before sorting.

```
[d, e, f, a, b, c]
```

And, here it is after.

```
[a, e, c, d, b, f]
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is possible to use a standard sorting algorithm to solve this issue.

I see that you are trying to just make these elements compare as zero to everything else, but the sorting algorithms available in Java make assumptions like transitivity of ordering that won't just take that and  treat it as "don't move these elements."